# Thinking Sphinx: How to render shorter excerpts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I'm using Thinking Sphinx in a Rails application combined with the jQuery autocomplete plugin for my search form. I'm searching on an Entry model with a "note" attribute (text data type). I'm using the following to return the excerpt:

```
<%= entry.excerpts.note %>
```

The "Excerpt Settings" section of [the documentation](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/excerpts.html) states that "At this point in time, Thinking Sphinx does not have the ability to customise the excerpts settings..." and that Sphinx uses a maximum length of 256 characters.

However, I would like to display around only 100 or so characters in my search results. I tried Rails' truncate method, but sometimes the matching term occurs after the 100th character (and is therefore not visible to the user).

Has anyone found a way to get TS to render shorter excerpts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet documented, but try setting `:excerpt_options` as part of your search parameters (they'll get passed along to the excerpt call):

```
Entry.search 'foo', :excerpt_options => {:limit => 100}
```